# nodejs / express: does calling next() automatically return the function it is called from?

Tags: node.js, express

Just wanted to get this out of my head:

when dealing with routing in Express/ Nodejs I want to know if calling `next()` always returns the function it is called from? Consider:

```
app.get('/users/:id?', function(req, res, next){
   //just as as example
   var err = doValidation(req);
   if (err) {
       next(err);
   } 
   next(); //will this ever be called?
});
```

In case of an error, will the second next() ever be called, or will a call for the first `next(err)` (automagically) return the function it is called from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if an error, both will be called. You want to do:

```
if(err) {
  return next(err);  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling `next()` **doesn't halt execution**, but `return` does, so **return next()** does return.